# Early stopping and regularization

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I have been using the mlp library on the sklearn on some data. I have been getting training set scores between 0.7 - 0.9 .However my test set scores have been really low. I assume this is due to over fitting and have read and understood that regularization (to help smooth weight/bias) and early stopping would help prevent this issue. However I am finding it hard to implement it, could someone help me with an implementation or guide me on the right path with a suitable link.

(The tutorial on regularization for clf on sklearn did not really help me as I found it to be confusing with little explanation)

Comment: what you got so far? if you are trying to build NN model I suggest use Keras or equivalent https://keras.io/

Answer (score 0):

Going off of the [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html), you can set..

```
early_stopping=True
```

Notes from sklearn:

> Whether to use early stopping to terminate training when validation score is not improving. If set to true, it will automatically set aside 10% of training data as validation and terminate training when validation score is not improving by at least tol for two consecutive epochs. Only effective when solver=’sgd’ or ‘adam’

You can modify the % allocated to validation set through this parameter.

```
validation_fraction=0.1
```

For regularization, they offer L2 regularization through the parameter `alpha`. For this I would highly recommend optimizing using grid-search.

```
alpha = 0.0001
```

**Edit**

Then I would try optimizing the learning rate. It's hard to tell based on that but it may be jumping over the "error valleys" or stuck in a local minima. Try 0.01 and 0.0005 and some in between using grid-search.

Also, be sure to scale your inputs if you aren't already, this could also be causing a problem.

**Edit**

If you are more of an audio learner, I'd try looking at some of the [videos from Udacity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iF8dRePlPUo&list=PLAwxTw4SYaPn_OWPFT9ulXLuQrImzHfOV) from their deep-learning program. They are really good at explaining things in simple terms. This could help you intuitively understand what is happening with your network instead of just trial and error (which is sometimes what it takes).

Comment: My solver is lbfgs, it seems to perform really badly when the solver is set to adam/sgd

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway, I am looking at grid search and it seems it would be helpful to use.